# multiple sliders with the same options all in one function?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI to create 6 sliders with the same options (survey).

I was wondering if there is a way to combine all of these sliders into one function, but have them operable individually?

If so, would it be something like this:

```
$('#slider').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this).closest('#slider');

    $($this).slider(
    {
        value: 100,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 25,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $('#amount').val('$' + ui.value);
        }
    });
    $('#amount').val($('#slider').slider("value"));
```

I looked around to see if I could find some related questions, but I still can't solve it. Right now, only the first out of 6 sliders is visible.

Comment: Try changing your #slider id to a class instead.

Comment: You are aware that they will have the same callback if you do like that. Are you sure about that?

Comment: @SimonEdström yeah exactly, that is one of my concerns about them being *individual.. When I change them all to a class, the value of one of the sliders reflects the other ones. Not essential.

Comment: Ok, but you should just add a unique callback insteed..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the issue is. This **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kK5FY/)** shows that it's just a basic setup. moving any slider shows that slider's value in the input field.

jQuery

```
$('.slider').slider({
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $('input:eq('+ $(this).index() +')').val(ui.value);
    }
});​
```

HTML

```
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<input /><br />
<input /><br />
<input /><br />
<input /><br />
<input /><br />
<input />​
```

Edit: updated code to reflect comment.

Comment: that's fine, but I want to have an input field for each unique slider. Would you happen to know how to do this? Could you implement something like, $this.closest('input').val(ui.value);    ?

Comment: exactly. Wow that was easier than I expected. Looks like over thought that one. Thanks j

Comment: No because the code above just focuses on the slider divs and the input elements, ignoring anything else.

Comment: ^ could it be configured like the link above?

Comment: yup. Looks like I just forgot the '.slider' inside $(this), thanks again!

Comment: i had to change my jQuery because I needed to actually find the parent of a parent, then from there, traverse up the tree, and find a child of a class.

Like this:

$(this).parent().find('.amount').val(ui.value);

fixed my problem.