# Is it possible to pass parameters to a jQuery UI slider

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a project that uses jQuery UI slider. It involves surveying people and the users have to tell how sure they are of something and that's where the slider comes in.

```
    $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-min1" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            jQuery( "#amount1" ).val(ui.value + "%" );
        }
    });
$( "#amount1" ).val($( "#slider-range-min1" ).slider( "value" ) + "%" );
});
```

Since one question may have 4-5 answers and each answers has a slider associated with it, for survey of 20 questions there will be too many individual slider functions. I can dynamically populate them but there must be a better way to do this. Like controlling all the slider with one function and simply passing the div id and input id to it.

I tried using class instead of ID, but when I do that the slider just disappears as jQuery Ui seem to attach few of its own class on runtime to the slider.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by passing parameters?  If you wish to have data available to the slider other than standard attributes (id, name, etc.), you can prefix custom attributes with data like so:  data-answer-data="some data".

Comment: pass data like div id and input id, i have mentioned them in my question as well

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer of tjscience is correct, but mayby incomplete for you. What about this:

```
<div class="container">
<input type="text" class="inputField"/>
<div id="answer-1" class="answer"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<input type="text" class="inputField"/>
<div id="answer-2" class="answer"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<input type="text" class="inputField"/>
<div id="answer-3" class="answer"></div>
</div>

$(".answer").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        var container = $(ui.handle).parents(".container");
        $(container).find(".inputField").val(ui.value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to simply make all of the answer divs sliders in one call?  If so this should work:

```
<div id="answer-1" class="answer"></div>
<div id="answer-2" class="answer"></div>
<div id="answer-3" class="answer"></div>

$(".answer").slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            jQuery( "#amount1" ).val(ui.value + "%" );
        }
});
```

Comment: Like I said earlier using class doesn't work for some reason. I have tried that and I am trying to get each slider fill up different input boxes, similar to this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841875/multiple-sliders-with-the-same-options-all-in-one-function but using id and hence i was looking if i can pass parameters to the function and if i can how do i do it. Thanks